# nginx failed after configering php

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-06-03 21:32:37 UTC; 17s ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 3056 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

```
Jun 03 21:32:34 sal systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Jun 03 21:32:37 sal nginx[3056]: nginx: [emerg] "fastcgi_pass" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:62
Jun 03 21:32:37 sal nginx[3056]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Jun 03 21:32:37 sal systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 03 21:32:37 sal systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 03 21:32:37 sal systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

conf file

```
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.socket;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
```

Comment: `nginx: [emerg] "fastcgi_pass" directive is duplicate` don't be having two of those.

Comment: always try `sudo nginx -t` before restarting nginx, you will get errors in that senario itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is clearly telling you, you can't use fastcgi_pass duplicated. So.

set like this if you using php socket:

```
}
# pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
#   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

or If you’re using unix socket change fastcgi_pass to:

```
}
# pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
#   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.socket;
}
```